# Facebook comments plugin - also post on facebook

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I've implemented Facebook comments on my site and they work just fine, but if I try to use the "also post on Facebook" i get this error:
http://pokit.org/get/img/ccecff74a87b9facf7e206b998f8bcd2.jpg

I tried searching around and couldn't find anything and I'm bad with javascript so I can't really look through Facebook's code to see what exactly is happening.

And again, comments work fine, the like page works fine, this is the only issue that I'm having.

My div for the comments looks like this:

```
<div class="fb-comments" data-href="{{url('/story/'.$name.'/'.$thestory->id)}}" data-numposts="5" data-order-by="social"></div>
```

and the data-href returns the correct page that I want.

Comment: _“but if I try to use the "also post on Facebook" i get this error”_ – if documented/official functionality is not working as expected, file a bug report: https://developers.facebook.com/bugs

Comment: Try to use the Open Graph debugger first (https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/), as suggested below. Issues like these can often be resolved with that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used Facebook's debugger tool https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/, and found out that I had problems with `<meta>` tags, after which everything was ok.